# The equivalent of Point and Size in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, size, point

I need to get the equivalent of Point and Size in C#.

When I tried to convert the code below from VB.NET to C#:

```
New Size(Sw, Sh)
```

I get this:

```
new Size(Sw, Sh);
```

Which gives an error; the error is:

> The type or namespace name 'Size' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have been using vb in vs2008, which does not prompt me to import `system.drawing`, perhaps it was doing it in the background, so I didn't expect to do it in c# in vs2008.

Comment: It should be the same, you are talking about  this size http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.aspx right?

Comment: Put your cursor between Size and the first `(`.  Press `Ctrl+.`  Does a dialog pop up prompting you to add a namespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Point pt = new Point(80, 80);
Size sz = new Size(100, 100);
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(pt, sz);
```

Your probably not using `system.drawing`

```
Using System.Drawing
```

And make sure you added it to your references in your project.